# Alliance Calendar Clicked Date Display

Tags: android, xamarin

In the Alliance Calendar Component,when I click on a date, it displays the info of the clicked date via Toast. Is there a way on how can I show it display it on a textview/edittext instead of a Toast message?This is on xamarin btw. Thank you

Here is the code from the Alliance Calendar itself.

```
[Activity (Label = "Alliance Calendar Demo", MainLauncher = true)]
public class CalendarDemoActivity : Activity
{
    CustomCalendar CalendarControl;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        CalendarControl = FindViewById<CustomCalendar>(Resource.Id.CalendarControl);
        CalendarControl.NextButtonText= "Next";
        CalendarControl.PreviousButtonText= "Prev";

        //CalendarControl.NextButtonVisibility= ViewStates.Invisible;
        //CalendarControl.PreviousButtonStyleId = Resource.Drawable.default_dim_selector;

        //CalendarControl.ShowOnlyCurrentMonth = true;
        CalendarControl.ShowFromDate = new DateTime();


        List<CustomCalendarData> customData = new List<CustomCalendarData>();

        customData = new List<CustomCalendarData>
        {
            new CustomCalendarData(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2)),
            new CustomCalendarData(DateTime.Now.AddDays(4)),
            new CustomCalendarData(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4))
        };
        CalendarControl.CustomDataAdapter = customData;


        CalendarControl.OnCalendarMonthChange += CalendarControl_CalendarMonthChange;
        CalendarControl.OnCalendarSelectedDate += CalendarControl_CalendarDateSelected;

    }

    private void CalendarControl_CalendarDateSelected(object sender, CalendarDateSelectionEventArgs e)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, e.SelectedDate.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }

    private void CalendarControl_CalendarMonthChange(object sender, CalendarNavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.MonthChange == CalendarHelper.MonthChangeOn.Next)
        {

        }
        else if (e.MonthChange == CalendarHelper.MonthChangeOn.Previous)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Replace the code for the Toast with something different

```
private void CalendarControl_CalendarDateSelected(object sender, CalendarDateSelectionEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something here in response to date selection
        // Toast.MakeText(this, e.SelectedDate.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
```

Comment: here's what i did                                                                              private void CalendarControl_CalendarDateSelected(object sender, CalendarDateSelectionEventArgs e)
  {  
 byWhentxt.Text = e.SelectedDate.ToString ("d");                             }                                                                                                                     i added a textview on this screen. now it's displaying the date in that textview . can i pass the data displayed to another textview in the previous activity ? i used intent but i got into a loop.

Comment: That is a different question - probably one that has been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv = findViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv); 

private void CalendarControl_CalendarDateSelected(object sender, CalendarDateSelectionEventArgs e)
{
   tv.Text =  e.SelectedDate.ToString();              
}
```